# os x app user authentication

Tags: macos, core-data

I am planning to create small os x application that uses core data to store some somewhat sensitive clients information.

Should that kind of app be protected with login? I am in doubt on this, since the person that will use this application is already logged in on his mac...or at least they should be.

I am asking this because I use mac about 8 years now, and I never see any program or application that asks me for username / password to use the program / application.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah you should use a password and use that password as the key used to encrypt the data you store.